# Long Table in Footnotesize

Tags: longtable, tablenotes

I am trying to generate a long table in footnote size. However, I can only get table note in footnote size and rest of the table is not in footnotesize. The MWE is given below:

```
     \documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
     \usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
     \usepackage{booktabs,longtable,tabularx}
     \usepackage{caption}
     \setlength{\LTcapwidth}{7in}
     \usepackage{ltablex}
     \usepackage{siunitx}
     \usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttablex}
     \begin{document}

     \begin{longtable}{l*{4}{S}} 
       \caption{Ordinary Least Square Estimations}\label{tab:te3}\\
       \caption*{%
     \footnotesize
         Note: This table provides the results of OLS. Four models are estimated here. Models details are provided in the main body of the document.
       }\\
       \toprule
       {\bfseries{}}  &{\bfseries(1)} & {\bfseries(2)} &{\bfseries(3)} &          {\bfseries(4)} \\%
       \endfirsthead
       \caption[]{-- continued from previous page}\\
       \toprule
       & {\bfseries(1)} & {\bfseries(2)} &{\bfseries(3)} & {\bfseries(4)}\\
       \midrule
       \endhead
       \bottomrule
       \addlinespace
       \multicolumn{5}{r}{\footnotesize Continued on next page} \\
       \endfoot
       \bottomrule
       \addlinespace
       \insertTableNotes\\
       \endlastfoot %
       \midrule
       A   & 0.022*** & 0.019*** & 0.021*** & 0.020*** \\
       B    & -0.002 & -0.008** & -0.010*** & -0.010** \\
       C  & 0.024 & -0.007 & -0.004 & -0.015 \\
       D    & -0.217*** & -0.314*** & -0.275*** & -0.262*** \\
       E   & -0.133 & -0.068 & -0.071 & -0.026 \\
       F   & 0.023 & 0.003 & 0.022 & 0.019 \\
       G    & -0.003*** & -0.003*** & -0.002** & -0.002** \\
       H    & -0.015 & -0.021** & -0.041*** & -0.045*** \\
       I   & -0.005** & -0.006*** & -0.006*** & -0.007*** \\
       J   & 0.184 & 0.346*** & 0.129 & 0.051 \\
       K & -0.006* & -0.007** & -0.007** & -0.009*** \\
       L & -0.014 & -0.022* & -0.021* & -0.023** \\
       M  & -0.006 & -0.001 & -0.004 & -0.002 \\
       N    & 0.001 & 0.004 & 0.009 & 0.003 \\
       O  & 0.01  & 0.017 & -0.003 & 0.003 \\
       P  & -0.077 & -0.146*** & -0.103** & -0.093** \\
       Q  & -0.022*** & -0.002 & -0.004 & -0.007 \\
       R   & 0.028*** & 0.035*** & 0.032*** & 0.027*** \\
       S    & 0.006 & 0.035*** & 0.026*** & 0.025*** \\
       T   & 0.0003 & -0.007 & 0.005 & -0.009 \\
       U   & -0.149** & -0.052 & 0.055 & 0.077 \\
       V   & -0.017* & -0.020** & -0.016* & -0.014* \\
       W     & -0.006 & -0.005 & 0.002 & -0.0004 \\
       Z    & -0.006 & -0.003 & -0.003 & -0.006 \\
       AB  & 0.004*** & 0.005*** & 0.005*** & 0.004*** \\
       AC  & -0.056** & -0.058** & -0.045* & -0.028 \\
       AD   & 1.985** & 0.856 & 0.178 & 0.306 \\
       AE    &       & -0.028*** & -0.012* & -0.012 \\
       AF   &       & 0.043*** & 0.044*** & 0.042*** \\
       AG    &       & -0.043*** & -0.037*** & -0.036*** \\
       AH   &       & -0.007 & -0.004 & -0.008 \\
       AI    &       & -0.003 & -0.004 & -0.003 \\
       AJ    &       & -0.014 & -0.003 & 0.004 \\
       BA  &       &       & -0.030*** & -0.031*** \\
       BC  &       &       & -0.038*** & -0.039*** \\
       BD  &       &       & -0.042*** & -0.044*** \\
       BE  &       &       & -0.025*** & -0.028*** \\
       BF  &       &       & -0.032*** & -0.036*** \\
       BH  &       &       & -0.034*** & -0.058*** \\
       BJ  &       &       & 0.006 & -0.013 \\
       BI  &       &       & -0.027*** & -0.048*** \\
       BL  &       &       & -0.028*** & -0.051*** \\
       BM  &       &       & 0.030*** & 0.012 \\
       BL * FC &       &       &       & -0.0005 \\
       BM * FC &       &       &       & 0.009** \\
       BC * FC &       &       &       & 0.013 \\
       BO * FC &       &       &       & 0.052*** \\
       BP * FC &       &       &       & -0.036** \\
       Constant & 0.131* & 0.039 & -0.032 & -0.03 \\
       \midrule
       Observations & 1,210 & 1,210 & 1,210 & 1,210 \\
       $R^2$    & 0.126 & 0.187 & 0.28  & 0.301 \\
       Adjusted $R^2$ & 0.106 & 0.164 & 0.254 & 0.272 \\
       Residual Std. Error & 0.003 & 0.003 & 0.002 & 0.002 \\
       $F$ Statistic & 6.325*** & 8.204*** & 10.552***  & 0.417*** \\
       \bottomrule
       \multicolumn{5}{c}{*p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01} \\
     \end{longtable}%

     \end{document}
```

Comment: Put `\footnotesize` before the `longtable`.